# mongodb criteria query for primary key _id?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I write the criteria query like this

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(id));
```

but the result is `{"_id":123456789123450}` which is not searching result. What I need to change to search the result using the criteria query on `_id`?

Comment: how is your id saved in db ?

Comment: How is `id` declared? Is it a `String`? An `ObjectId`? Can you show us a little bit more of your code?

Comment: id is declared as int64

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways to do this

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(new ObjectId(<id value>)));
```

Or Spring data MongoDB's findById

```
org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.findById(String id);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-

Comment: Cant we do this using MongoRepository or CrudRepository query ?

Comment: 2nd option is using CrudRepository.

Comment: First option worked perfectly for me! thanks :)